# Python looping only returns the last results

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to combine an ArcGIS tool in the loop to write multiple results (code below), but came across the issue that my code only outputs the result when `i = 80`? I'm expecting to have 16 outputs with `i` from 10 to 80.

```
for i in range(10, 90, 10):
    mjrdno = math.ceil(i*0.7/2); 
    mnrdno = i*0.7 - mjrdno; 
    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(outFolder, "mjrd_network_"+str(i), inFolder+"\mjrd_sample.shp", "", mjrdno, 200)
    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(outFolder, "mnrd_network_"+str(i), inFolder+"\mnrd_sample.shp", "", mnrdno, 200)
```

Could anyone help?

Cheers

Comment: Use indentation, not a semicolon to give the body of the loop. What you have doesn't really look like valid Python.

Comment: Please make sure that the indentation here matches your code *exactly*. You didn't paste it correctly into the question so it looked wrong.

Comment: @JohnColeman Does it run without syntax errors for you?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I can't run it at all without the arcpy module -- whatever that is, but I could tell what loop OP was trying to do and then add the indentations.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm just curious what fixed the problem because OP obviously could run what code they had. But it might have just been that the last couple lines weren't indented at all.

Comment: Another problem I have is that if the my input shapefile name starts with "t", it also gives an error. Presumably  `\t` means something? What might be a better way to index the location of my shapefile then?

Comment: @mohowu Use `r` before file path strings, like this: `r'C:\Path\To\File``. This means that Python ignores escape characters like `\n` and `\t` and will just treat the backslash as a backslash. (\t  is tab, just so you know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of a loop should be indented relative to its header and you don't need semicolons to terminate statements. Properly indented, I think that this is what you want:

```
for i in range(10, 90, 10):
    mjrdno = math.ceil(i*0.7/2)
    mnrdno = i*0.7 - mjrdno
    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(outFolder, "mjrd_network_"+str(i), inFolder+"\mjrd_sample.shp", "", mjrdno, 200)
    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(outFolder, "mnrd_network_"+str(i), inFolder+"\mnrd_sample.shp", "", mnrdno, 200)
```

Comment: Cheers, that works great. I mainly write in R, but recently have to use ArcGIS to do some spatial stuff. Without any background in Python, I'm really struggling with some basic bits and pieces.

Comment: Oh, maybe the edits to the question were too slow for your solution :)

Comment: @mohowu If you are coming from R you might want to look at pandas which is (roughly) equivalent: http://pandas.pydata.org/ O'Reilly has a nice text which describes how to use it.